# App.js functionality loss over public internet using NODE JS AND EXPRESS

Tags: node.js, express

Node js + express is displaying great on localhost. My issue is, is that after I display static page which is doing it's job, my app.js script is not firing from the outside world. But when running locally it works like it is suppose to.

```
    //send html page to user
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
    app.use(express.static('public'));
    app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html'); //send the file


    });
 //My app 
 // everything below this line does not work
```

I followed the direction from express but still app.js is not firing from the outside world. Again it hits great on local. Any help that would be greatly appreciated!

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: What does "is not firing" exactly mean?

Comment: anything after the express function does not work. So basically my node server is just displaying my html.

Comment: why `node_modules` folder serving as static content?

Comment: still learning, I got rid of that line. @FazalRasel

Comment: Server side code is not executing. @ zerkms and @FazalRasel

Comment: Is your site being cached by a CDN perhaps?

Comment: @Dshiz yes actually~! good call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I was able to deduce that you are behind a sockets enabled CDN and it has not cashed your server-side sockets. Turn off cashing if you are actively developing your site.